# ATI 4850 on 13.04 64bit

Tags: drivers, ati, 64-bit, 13.04, fglrx

To those that can help,I am guessing that you have seen a variant of this problem many times before. However after doing my best to try to use the various fixes mentioned across various pages, I have finally given up! 
The problem is that I cannot run unity - because I cannot install the legacy drivers properly in 13.04.
When I input `sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy` step after doing the previous 3 steps (which seem to run fine) I get the following output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fglrx-amdcccle-legacy fglrx-legacy-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed
  fglrx-amdcccle-legacy fglrx-legacy fglrx-legacy-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/72.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 24.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-legacy-dev.
(Reading database ... 201264 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx-legacy-dev (from .../fglrx-legacy-dev_2%3a8.97.100.7-makson1~raring2_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking fglrx-legacy (from .../fglrx-legacy_2%3a8.97.100.7-makson1~raring2_amd64.deb) ...
One or more files have been altered since installation.
Uninstall will not be completed. See /etc/ati/fglrx-uninstall.log for details.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-legacy_2%3a8.97.100.7-makson1~raring2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle-legacy.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle-legacy (from .../fglrx-amdcccle-legacy_2%3a8.97.100.7-makson1~raring2_amd64.deb) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-legacy_2%3a8.97.100.7-makson1~raring2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help is much appreciated. I am an Ubuntu noob.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

And report back what was the result.
It is a package manager problem but I would be surprised if you could use that driver on your system. As far as AMD is concerned you have legacy hardware. When people use these proprietary drivers there seems to be lot of problems with hardware that falls into this category because AMD has dropped the support.

Try using open source drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

But remember that when you try different drivers you should have only one installed at a time or there will be trouble.

Comment: I suggest you start a new question about not being able to use multiple displays as we have made progress and now there is clear focus. Include the information you have gathered (the fact that you made fresh install + output from those terminal commands).                                                   After that we could delete our comments here to clean up this mess.

Comment: After reinstalling 13.04 the system has managed to install the open source drivers which seem to be working fine under gnome. I cant boot unity but that is a separate issue for which I have set up another question for. Just FYI the driver installed on my system is Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV770

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

And restart your computer.

Do note that these packages are not officially supported by Ubuntu, so use them at your own risk. If something goes wrong, you can purge the packages by running following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:makson96/fglrx
```

Comment: After you get that error, try `apt-get -f install` to force an install of the files that didn't get loaded because of the error. Then try `apt-get upgrade` again, `apt-get -f install` back and forth until only the package that has the error is left.

Comment: Now, to solve the unmet dependencies, check this: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to download the drivers from AMD's website. The ones in the official repositories are not the latest, and they really don't run well. fglrx by the way are **NOT** the same drivers as the ones provided by AMD.

For New cards Here : http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-3LINBetaDriver.aspx

These are the latest Beta drivers for Linux.

Refer to top answer on `/questions/18747/` for installation.

For Radeon HD 4850 you need this one :
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx

AMD Radeon HD 4000/3000/2000 Series
AMD Radeon HD Series AGP
AMD Mobility Radeon HD 4000/3000/2000 Series

Comment: Provide your set up please. Processor, GPU and model.

Comment: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx

By the way, what exactly do you mean by "can't start unity"? do you boot up to a black screen without login prompt?

Comment: **This is not a driver problem**
In virtual terminal `Ctrl+Alt+F1` run `unity --reset` then reboot.
If it doesn't work run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` then `sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity` followed by `unity --reset` and `unity --replace`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot this is 13.04, reset is deprecated, replaced.
What's interesting is the error output for `unity --replace`. Try running `sudo apt-get install unity-panel` or `apt-get --reinstall install`. Better yet is to search for unity in Synaptic (if you have it) `sudo apt-get install synaptic` and install `unity-panel`.
Did the legacy drivers work for your GPU?
If you haven't customized your desktop then I'd suggest reinstalling unity, `/questions/131016/`.

Comment: that's a repository issue. Install from Synaptic instead of `apt-get`, it'll resolve on its own.

Comment: Yes, just so we can clean up the conversation and make them a bit more on point, maybe you can just google for reps or make sure you have additional and restricted authenticated first.

Answer (score 0):

Jay! 
I just installed fresh 13.04 and I in "System Settings - Details" I have "Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV770" in the "Graphics". I have ati 4850 too. 
Do you know what is "Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV770"?
And did you find the way to install drivers on 12.04, 12.10 or 13.04? 
I've tried so many ways of installing them on 12.04 and 12.10 and failed again and again. I have great performance in OS, but in games I have slideshows, but on Windows exactly the same games works just fine.

Comment: I have the driver as you, to be honest I am not sure exactly what Gallium is but I am not complaining as long as it works! I don't play games so I dont know whether I have the same problem as you regarding that. Are you running unity?